# How to enable SHAKE/STIR in node js

Tags: node.js, twilio, phone-call

I am currently working on a project that involves implementing SHAKEN/STIR (Signature-based Handling of Asserted information using toKENs/Secure Telephone Identity Revisited) in a Node.js application to combat robocalls and caller ID spoofing.

I would like to seek your expertise in understanding how to integrate the SHAKEN/STIR framework into our Node.js project. Specifically, I am looking for guidance on the following aspects:

- Overview of SHAKEN/STIR: Can you provide a brief explanation of what SHAKEN/STIR is and how it helps in reducing fraudulent calls?
- Implementation Steps: What are the key steps involved in integrating SHAKEN/STIR in a Node.js project? Are there any specific libraries or APIs that we should use for this implementation?
- Twilio Integration: How can we leverage Twilio's APIs and services to authenticate and verify incoming calls using the SHAKEN/STIR framework?
- Testing and Deployment: What are the best practices for testing the SHAKEN/STIR implementation in our Node.js application? How should we deploy the project once the implementation is complete?

I would greatly appreciate your insights and guidance on this matter. Your expertise in Node.js development and telecommunications technology will be invaluable in helping me successfully implement SHAKEN/STIR in our project.

Comment: What have you tried so far?